# '90s time travel movie where the villain is seen in black & white photos, and is following people through time

Tags: story-identification, movie, time-travel

I have a vague recollection of a time travel TV movie from the '90s, where the villain is seen in a variety of black and white photos, and is following a group of people through time. The antagonist/time traveller is a somewhat known actor in this style of movie, and looks somewhat similar looking to the modern Marvel character "Loki", with a white complexion and slicked back, black hair (but at the time he was quite a bit older). It was a C or D-list movie that played regularly, and I'm fairly certain "time" was in the title.

Comment: There's "Time After Time", where H G Wells pursues Jack the Ripper, but that was 1979 and I don't recall any BW photos.

Answer (score 6):

Might this be *[Time Chasers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_Chasers)* (1994)...?

[image]

> Physics teacher and amateur pilot Nick Miller (Matthew Bruch) has finally completed his quest of enabling time travel, via a Commodore 64 and his small airplane. After being inspired by a television commercial for GenCorp, he uses a ruse to bring out both a GenCorp executive and a reporter from a local paper. To Nick's surprise, the reporter is Lisa Hansen (Bonnie Pritchard), an old high school flame. One trip to 2041 later and Gencorp's executive, Matthew Paul (Peter Harrington), quickly arranges Nick a meeting with CEO J.K. Robertson (George Woodard). Impressed by the potential of time travel, Robertson offers Nick a licensing agreement on the technology.
>
> The following week, Nick and Lisa meet at the supermarket and go on a date to the 1950s. However, another trip to 2041 reveals that GenCorp abused Nick's time travel technology, creating a dystopian future. In an attempt to tell J.K. about how GenCorp inadvertently ruined the future. J.K. dismisses the eventuality, and states that there's enough time to worry about how to fix it before it happens. J.K. sees Nick as a threat to GenCorp, and due to the association with the U.S. Government, considers Nick's actions as treason. Nick and Lisa escape GenCorp and spend the remainder of the film trying to reverse the damage to the future. When J.K. finds out about this, he and Matt try to shoot down Nick's plane, killing Lisa in the process while Nick jumps out before the plane crashes. This ultimately culminates in a fight in 1777 during the American Revolution, the deaths of the present Nick and Robertson, and the destruction of the time machine before the original demo, thus ensuring that the majority of the film's events never happen in the first place. The film ends with the now current Nick (now aware of the danger of his time machine) sabotaging his demonstration, and doing a pitch of how an elderly skydiver would be a better ad campaign for J.K.'s company. Furious about being misled, J.K. fires Matt. Nick deletes the eight 5¼" floppy disks that make time travel possible. At the end of the film, Nick talks to Lisa in the supermarket as he did in the previous timeline.

The antagonist (a corporate CEO who wants to use time-travel as a weapon) resembles your description, he does pursue the protagonists (a physics professor who invented the mechanism for time-travel, and a reporter) through time, and he is pictured in black & white photos at one point in the film:

[image]

[image]

Comment: This isn't the movie I was thinking of but it is very similar to what I described!

Answer (score 5):

You're describing the plot of [Thrill Seekers](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0204686/) (AKA The Time Shifters) from 1999 with Casper Van Dien and Martin Sheen. The Loki-like antagonist that appears in all the old photos is played by [Julian Richings](http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-vMPyqZQncug/VPJC58MdtPI/AAAAAAAAPK4/LubO-8z_yOA/s1600/Sunpernatural.jpg). You can read more about it [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thrill_Seekers_(film)), and here's the trailer:

Comment: Some how my account got deleted but THANK YOU WALT - this is the movie I was seeking.

Comment: @Matthew Please follow [these instructions](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts) to reclaim your former account and be able to formally accept Walt's answer.